# Referencing TargetElements when when authoring Adaptive Cards

Tags: c#, json, adaptive-cards

I am authoring an Adaptive Card in C# and need to add an Image with a ToggleVisibilityAction. The JSON equivalent is:

```json
{
  "type": "Image",
  "selectAction": {
    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
    "title": "expand",
    "targetElements": [ "REFERENCE_1", "REFERENCE_2",]
  },
  "url": "MY_IMAGE_URL",
  "altText": "visible"
}
```

In the above `REFERENCE_1` and `REFERENCE_2` are the Id fields of the elements I want to target.

When authoring it in C#, I have

```html
new AdaptiveImage()
{
  SelectAction = new AdaptiveToggleVisibilityAction()
  {
    Title = "collapse",
    TargetElements = REFERENCE_COLLECTION_HERE, 
  },
}
```

My challenge is that the JSON version accepts a string reference with an `Id` of the TargetElement but the C# version expects a `List<AdaptiveTargetElement>` where `REFERENCE_COLLECTION_HERE` is. How do I manage to reference the TargetElement while being able to add it where I want it in my card layout.

Comment: Yea thats an oversight, you'll see that a lot of things in C# are different or not possible. The general recommendation is to always use the card as JSON and load it in c#. Authoring cards in C# as Objects is sort of deprecated especially since templating is available. Templates (reusable cards etc) is literarily impossible with c# aswell. 

Try to keep your card in json is always what you should do.

Comment: Okay thank you @TimCadenbach, but it is possible to dynamically add items to cards at runtime right? I am considering a situation where I have a list and I am not sure how many items I will need to add.

Comment: Sure! with templating thats more than possible. 

Look at this example : https://www.madewithcards.io/cards/expense-report-20 you can see that there's no "data" in the card as such, all numbers etc come from the data. 

The same is possible for lists and list items. You create one element for how the list items should look bind it to the list in the data and its getting rendered, few more infos are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/language

Comment: Thank you very much... I will start moving to templating.

Comment: Where are you using that card, in a bot?

Comment: Yes, I am using it in a bot.

Comment: @MichaelDera - Is my answer acceptable? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: Yes @KyleDelaney, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `AdaptiveTargetElement` objects instead of strings:

```
new AdaptiveImage()
{
    SelectAction = new AdaptiveToggleVisibilityAction()
    {
        Title = "collapse",
        TargetElements = new List<AdaptiveTargetElement>
        {
            new AdaptiveTargetElement("REFERENCE_1"),
            new AdaptiveTargetElement("REFERENCE_2"),
        },
    },
}
```

You can see the documentation for them here: https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/TargetElement.html

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.... I have been advised to switch to the templating approach, but I will use this for code I have not yet migrated to that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please try out below in C#:

```
private Attachment GenerateCard(NewsInfo newsResult){
int indexCount = 0;
var card = new AdaptiveCard("1.3");
var list = new List<AdaptiveElement>();

newsResult.articles = newsResult.articles.Take(5).ToArray();

foreach (var item in newsResult.articles)
{
    list.Add(new AdaptiveContainer
    {
        Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>
            {
                new AdaptiveContainer
                {
                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>
                    {
                        new AdaptiveColumnSet
                        {
                            Columns = new List<AdaptiveColumn>
                            {
                                new AdaptiveColumn
                                {
                                    Width = AdaptiveColumnWidth.Auto,
                                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>
                                    {
                                        new AdaptiveTextBlock
                                        {
                                            Text = $"{item.title}",
                                            Wrap = true,
                                        }
                                    }
                                },

                                new AdaptiveColumn
                                {
                                    Width = "30px",
                                    Spacing = AdaptiveSpacing.Small,
                                    SelectAction = new AdaptiveToggleVisibilityAction
                                    {
                                        Title = "Toggle",
                                        TargetElements = new List<AdaptiveTargetElement>
                                        {
                                            new AdaptiveTargetElement
                                            {
                                                ElementId = $"CardContent_{indexCount}",
                                            },
                                            new AdaptiveTargetElement
                                            {
                                                ElementId = $"chevronDown{indexCount}",
                                            },
                                            new AdaptiveTargetElement
                                            {
                                                ElementId = $"chevronUp{indexCount}",
                                            },
                                        }
                                    },
                                    VerticalContentAlignment = AdaptiveVerticalContentAlignment.Center,
                                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>
                                    {
                                        new AdaptiveImage
                                        {
                                            Id = $"chevronDown{indexCount}",
                                            Url = new Uri("https://adaptivecards.io/content/down.png"),
                                        },
                                        new AdaptiveImage
                                        {
                                            Id = $"chevronUp{indexCount}",
                                            Url = new Uri("https://adaptivecards.io/content/up.png"),
                                            IsVisible = false
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new AdaptiveContainer
                        {
                            Id = $"CardContent_{indexCount}",
                            IsVisible = false,
                            Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>
                            {
                                new AdaptiveContainer
                                {
                                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>
                                    {
                                        new AdaptiveImage
                                        {
                                            Url = new Uri($"{item.image}"),
                                            PixelWidth = 20,
                                            IsVisible = false
                                        },

                                        new AdaptiveTextBlock
                                        {
                                            Text = $"*{item.description}*",
                                            IsSubtle = true,
                                            Wrap = true
                                        },

                                        new AdaptiveTextBlock
                                        {
                                            Text = $"{item.content}",
                                            IsSubtle = true,
                                            Wrap = true
                                        },

                                        new AdaptiveTextBlock
                                        {
                                            Text = $"*{item.publishedAt}*",
                                            IsSubtle = true,
                                            Wrap = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                },

                                new AdaptiveColumnSet
                                {
                                    Columns = new List<AdaptiveColumn>
                                    {
                                       new AdaptiveColumn
                                        {
                                            Width = AdaptiveColumnWidth.Stretch,
                                            Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>
                                            {
                                                new AdaptiveActionSet
                                                {
                                                    Actions =
                                                    {
                                                        new AdaptiveOpenUrlAction()
                                                        {
                                                            Url = new Uri($"{item.source.url}"),
                                                            Title = $"{item.source.name}",
                                                            Style = "positive",
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
    });

    indexCount++;
}

card.Body = list;

return new Attachment()
{
    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
    Content = card
};}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).